# C# decimal precision function

Tags: c#, math, precision

I have a decimal function:

```
public decimal NGD(long TotalPages, long XHits, long YHits, long BothHits)
{
    return ((Math.Max(XHits, YHits)-BothHits)/(TotalPages - Math.Min(XHits, YHits)));
}
```

upon printing the arguments I get NGD(44000000000,36100000,5630000,3580000) which translates to `return ((36100000 - 3580000 )/(44000000000 - 5630000));` yet in my application I get a 0 when it should be 0.00073918549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using integer division, which truncates the result. Use `return ((decimal)(36100000 - 3580000 )/((decimal)(44000000000 - 5630000)));` for decimal division.

Comment: Note that when the `(decimal)` casts are placed like this, the subtraction is still performed with `long`. This might be good if it can be guaranteed that it will not overflow (difference must be withing `long.MinValue` and `long.MaxValue`). But you can also use `return ((decimal)Math.Max(XHits, YHits) - BothHits) / ((decimal)TotalPages - Math.Min(XHits, YHits));` in which case the subtractions will be performed as `decimal` "minus".

Answer (score 2):

You're doing integer division, which can only return a truncated integer.

You need to cast one operand to a non-integral type (probably `decimal`).

Comment: Yeah, his return type for the method is `decimal`, so `double` it is not.

Answer (score 0):

All of your arithmetic is done with `long` (`System.Int64`) which is an *integer* type. Only after the division is finished (giving an integer result) will the quotient be converted to `decimal`.

Consider casting your dividend (or even just the leading term of it) to `decimal` (`System.Decimal`). Then all other `long` values will automatically be "promoted" to `decimal` along the way.

Of course you may instead change one parameter (or all parameters) to have type `decimal`. No explicit cast will be needed to convert an expression of type `long` into an method argument of type `decimal`.